# Any danger to doing beta test with randoms using Test Flight App?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, testflight

Recently I've completed a beta version of my app and want to recruit some users to test it. I've been using Test Flight App to send the App to my designer so I'm probably going to do it that way. I was just wondering, is there any danger in doing this? I was thinking of going on some message boards to recruit testers so I obviously won't know the people personally. Is it possible that someone could reverse engineer the .ipa and steal the code?

Comment: Not programing related problem; But good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can run it it can be reverse engineered

This is true for all you users including the testers.

All you can do is release your app and hope for the best.

Ask yourself:

- Is it *really* that groundbreaking that you have to be scarred
  someone will steal it?
- If someone does steal your code are you able to prove any claims?

If you really wrote something great and new someone else will create something simmilar from scratch so there is *nothing* you can do, but keep your logs and document your work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Regarding "if someone does steal your code are you able to prove any claims?", what could I do to prove my claims? I haven't submitted it to the app store. I do have it in a repository on Git hub.

Comment: I´m not a lawyer but I usually Keep all documents and emails and use a external source controll server (github).